# ISDEV : fatal error -1501 couldn't compress file

Tags: windows-installer, packaging, installshield-2012, installshield-2014

I'm new to Install shield professional 2015 ,our project was previously handled by other team,they were using Installshield 12 , after that we were told to migrate to Install shield 2015 (we don't have the copy of IS12)
they were building the code using the IS 12 standalone build,
they used `IsSaBld.exe` to build the Install shield project through command line
so to build the same project using IS 15 professional.

I just Changed the paths  and changed the exe name from IsSaBld.exe(in our build system code which is a bat file) to `ISCmdBld.exe`(which is  present in `/IS15/System/`)

Project is building fine no other errors except few file missing errors, I was able to solve those but not this error:

> ISDEV : fatal error -1501 couldn't compress file
>   "\win32\dll\Admin.dll" into
>   "\my_sdk_mm\MSIImage\DiskImages\DISK1\MERGEM~1.cab"

Even if the file is present.

Please some one help me to solve this issue
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your path is incomplete. Windows paths don't start with "\"

Comment: Sorry , I have not given the complete path due to some restrictions. the file is present in the exact path actually

Comment: The complete error message is

Comment: ISDEV : fatal error -1501 couldn't compress file "E:Project\dlls\win32\dll\Admin.dll" into "E:\Output\my_sdk_mm\MSIImage\DiskImages\DISK1\MERGEM~1.cab"

Comment: I'm not sure what's going wrong. Whenever I've received a 1501 error it's always been because the file was missing at that location.

Comment: Thanks a lot jbudreau , your suggestion got worked, Windows is not able to resolve paths if it contains double \\ slashes but it is working in command line , so I replaced \\ with \ , it works. thanks a lot.